# API call using angular js $http post method

Tags: angularjs, http

I need to do API call using angular js $http:

JOSN format:

```
{
jobData : {"companyName":"companyname", "designation":"Javascript developer", "hiringManagerEmail":"atul@xyz.com", "industry":"automotive", "location":"chennai", "typeOfWork":"full time", "jobDescription":"abcdefghijklmnop", "rolesAndResponsiblities":"Reviewing current systems.Presenting ideas for system improvements, including cost proposals. Working closely with analysts, designers and staff. Producing detailed specifications and writing the program codes. Testing the product in controlled, real situations before going live. Preparation of training manuals for users.Maintaining the systems once they are up and running", "minEducation":"bachelors", "minEdu_fieldOfStudy":"computer science", "prefEducation":"masters", "prefEdu_filedOfStudy":"computerscience", "recruiterNotes":"must be from premium institute", "minExperience":"5", "maxExperience":"7", "requiredSkills":[ "java", "spring", "hibernate" ], "goodToHaveSkills":[ "jsp", "jquery", "sql" ], "requiredSoftSkills":[ "team leadership", "project management" ], "goodToHaveSoftSkills":[ "growth mindset", "management skills" ], "preferredCertifications":[ "sun certified java programmer (SCJP)" ], "minCertification":[ "sun certified java associate (SCJA)" ], "workPermits":[ "united states of america", "singapore" ], "visaStatus":[ "united states of america - valid till december 2015", "singapore - valid till may 2016" ], "minSalaryBand":"7.5", "maxSalaryBand":"10.0", "shiftTiming":"daytime", "startTime":"", "endTime":"", "numberOfPositions":"2", "joining":"30 days after offer", "closingNoticePeriod":"no", "checklist":[ "does the candidate has any experience working in the automotive industry?", "is the candidate willing to work abroad if required?", "does the candidate have good communication skills?", "is the candidate passionate enough for the company?" ], "needProfilesBy":"20 september 2015" }}
```

API call:

```
function postJob(){

          var job = {
                  "companyName":"company",
                  "designation":"software engineer",
                  "needProfilesBy":"20 september 2015"
                };
           return $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : api + 'job',
            transformRequest: transformRequestAsFormPost,
            data: {'jobData': job},
          }).then(postJobComplete)
            .catch(exception.catcher('XHR Failed for post signup'));


          function postJobComplete (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
          }

        }
```

transformRequest.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.core')
        .factory('transformRequestAsFormPost', transformRequestAsFormPost);

    transformRequestAsFormPost.$inject = [];
    /* @ngInject */
    function transformRequestAsFormPost() {

        function transformRequest(data, getHeaders) {

            var headers = getHeaders();

            return (serializeData(data));

        }

        return (transformRequest);

        function serializeData(data) {

            if (!angular.isObject(data)) {

                return ((data == null) ? '' : data.toString());

            }

            var buffer = [];

            for (var name in data) {

                if (!data.hasOwnProperty(name)) {

                    continue;

                }

                var value = data[ name ];

                buffer.push(
                    encodeURIComponent(name) +
                    '=' +
                    encodeURIComponent((value == null) ? '' : value)
                );

            }

            var source = buffer
                .join('&')
                .replace(/%20/g, '+')
            ;

            return (source);

        }

    }
})();
```

I am trying send data using with 'jobData' but getting error as

error:

> "Bad Request"
>   exception:"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException"
>   message: "Required String parameter 'jobData' is not present" path:
>   "/job" status: 400

Comment: Your API seems to expect a string for `jobData`, but you are sending an object.

Comment: Can you help me to send jobData as string? I don't how to specify here. I am new to this

Comment: I suggest you change your API to accept an Object instead of a String which includes companyName, designation and other fields (or) you can convert  your `job` object to a string using `JSON.stringify()`, send the JSON string in your request, receive the String parameter and parse it to an Object in your controller using an `ObjectMapper`. Choice is yours :)

Comment: I have this line

data: {'jobData': job},

 to :
         
data: JSON.stringify({'jobData': JSON.stringify(job)})


Request Data sending as:

jobData: "{"companyName":"companyname","designation":"software engineer","needProfilesBy":"20 september 2015"}"

Now also getting same error.